# Difference between Database.insert(list) and Database.insert(list,false)

Tags: apex

I could not understand whats the Difference between Database.insert(list) and Database.insert(list,false)

Comment: please take time to read the docs : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_insert_2

Comment: You can go through this link for your easy understanding : http://prosenjit-sarkar-sfdc.blogspot.in/2015/04/partial-bulk-insert-via-apex.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Just an example**

If you are inserting 5 records.

3 having all the required fields value and remaining 2 records missing required fields value.

if you use

`Database.insert(list)` will thrown an exception and it will not insert any one of the records.

but

if you use `Database.insert(list, false)` It will insert 3 records successfully and rest 2 records(required fields missing) will not be inserted.

`Database.insert(list, false)` In this scenario you will not get any exception

---

**Example with code.** We know Account's Name field is required.

```
List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();

lstAccount.add(new Account(Name = 'Test Account 001'));
lstAccount.add(new Account(Name = 'Test Account 002'));
lstAccount.add(new Account(Name = 'Test Account 003'));
lstAccount.add(new Account());
lstAccount.add(new Account());

Database.insert(lstAccount);
```

Try this code you will get error.

> Line: 9, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception
>   on row 3; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are
>   missing: [Name]: [Name]

Now run below code

```
List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();

lstAccount.add(new Account(Name = 'Test Account 001'));
lstAccount.add(new Account(Name = 'Test Account 002'));
lstAccount.add(new Account(Name = 'Test Account 003'));
lstAccount.add(new Account());
lstAccount.add(new Account());

Database.insert(lstAccount, false);
```

And check your org you can see 3 records created `Test Account 001,Test Account 002 and Test Account 003`